# Checkstyle Eclipse plugin doesn't work

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, checkstyle

I'm using eclipse checkstyle plugin with Juno Eclipse distribution. Anytime the code is checked for checkstyle error I get the following error:

```
cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Unable to instantiate DoubleCheckedLocking
```

Does anybody know how to fix this problem? Is it a plugin compatibility issue or something else?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The DoubleCheckedLocking check has been removed in Checkstyle 5.6 and must be manually removed from your Checkstyle configuration.

See also: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3571442&group_id=29721&atid=397078

Comment: How can I remove DoubleCheckedLocking configuration?

Comment: Editing the checkstyle configuration file using a plain text editor iss the way to go. The location of this file should be visible in the checkstyle configuration page in your eclipse checkstyle settings.

Comment: Answer doesn't provide actual solution, only excuse for cause.

Comment: Just comment out:   <!-- <module name="DoubleCheckedLocking"/>   -->

Answer (score 26):

Open the Checkstyle preferences, create your own Check Configuration, go into your own check configuration, find the TreeWalker module, click it and then un-check the DoubleCheckedLocking. As simple as that.

[image]

Comment: With picture is always the best way to show a problem.

Answer (score 2):

just comment or remove "DoubleCheckedLocking" from the checkstyle file and it will work

Answer (score 0):

- Under your Eclipse Workspace Search for file **internal_config__*.xml**
- Remove the following line from the file

  <module name="DoubleCheckedLocking"/>
- Reload Workspace.

This will work for any discontinued module which produces the error message "Unable to instantiate"