# Checkstyle for external configuration file in Eclipse Juno

Tags: java, eclipse

When building the java project, I'm encountering an error while building the project itself.

```
"cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Unable to instantiate DoubleCheckLocking"
```

[image]

I tried the solution mentioned in the question below - 
[Checkstyle Eclipse plugin doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795935/checkstyle-eclipse-plugin-doesnt-work)

But in my case the configuration options are read only!

[image]

I'm using eclipse Juno - 
Version: Juno Service Release 2
Build id: 20130225-0426

How make these options editable in case of using an external configuration file?

Comment: I had a similar problem with certain other (non-Checkstyle) configuration settings. In my case, something strange was going on with file permissions. Could you try running eclipse as administrator to change the settings? That worked in my case.

Answer (score 1):

The [Eclipse-Checkstyle integration plugin documentation](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/advanced_configtypes.html) does mention

> External configurations can by default be edited if the configuration file is writable.

[image: http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/images/new_external_config.jpg]

> If you have a carefully crafted configuration file (with nice comments and all that) - which you don't want to "destroy" accidentally by using the configuration editor - you can use the Protect Checkstyle configuration file option.
>   When enabled the configuration editor will not touch your file even if it is write enabled.

Of course, check if your externa config file is writable.
But also check if your external config isn't "protected", .

Answer (score 0):

DoubleCheckLocking has been removed from Checkstyle 5.6 and later.